# vagrant: 404 browser when try to access on vvv.test

Tags: vagrant

I installed correctly vagrant but when I try to open vvv.test browser don't allow to show me the page

[image]

no erros when I initialized vagrant

[image]

I work on windows 10, a new installation with no particular environment. I use vagrant on my laptop and no problem incurred. On this new installation if I use the last version of vagrant I can't initialized vagrant because an error of vagrant to download the package. I installed the same version of vagrant on my laptop vagrant_2.2.10_x86_64 and I can do all except for the error of browser.

I can access without problem with ssh.

I don't know why I have this problem

Comment: I have also run into this error. On macOS Big Sur, still looking for a solution.